# Windows Server 2008 HPC Edition is permanently logging Audit Success for RDP sessions

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp, windows-event-log

A Windows Server 2008 HPC Edition box is permanently logging Logon and Logoff tasks for the user who is connected to it via RDP every few seconds. Is there a way to just log the user initiated logon and logoff events?

[image: Security log]

Typical Logoff events look like this:

```
An account was logged off.

Subject:
Security ID:        DOMAIN\USERX
Account Name:       USERX
Account Domain:     DOMAIN
Logon ID:       0x1c4f9eb

Logon Type:         3
```

and typical Logon events look like this:

```
An account was successfully logged on.

Subject:
Security ID:        NULL SID
Account Name:       -
Account Domain:     -
Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Type:         3
New Logon:
Security ID:        DOMAIN\USERX
Account Name:       USERX
Account Domain:     DOMAIN
Logon ID:       0x1c54963
Logon GUID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Process Information:
Process ID:     0x0
Process Name:       -

Network Information:
Workstation Name:   XX-YY
Source Network Address: -
Source Port:        -
```

There are only two users connected via RDP and this behaviour doesn't depend upon them doing anything specific on the server.

Comment: What is the user engaging in after they log in? Something must be triggering those 4624/4634 events. Can you post the contents (pls remove confidential data) of the event, e.g. what is the logon type?

Comment: @LuckyLuke I have added more information to the question.